# Wrapping a list of Checkboxes in a Datalist or Repeater

Tags: repeater

I have a long list of checkboxes bound in a repeater is there a way of wrapping them so instead of having 1 long list wrapping it across 3 or 4 colouns side by side say 7 items long.

Is it easier to do this with a repeater or a Datalist?

Cheers

Ste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to use one of the repeating controls like the DataList control that has a RepeatDirection property:

```
MyDataList.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal
```

Or, you can play around with the HTML markup in the ItemTemplate of the Repeater control.  [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728129/horizontal-view-in-repeater) for possible clues on this.

Comment: Was having troubles styling the textboxlist this works perfectly cheers for taking the time to answer

Answer (score 0):

If you truly only need a list of check boxes why not use a CheckBoxList and set the [RepeatColumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.repeatcolumns.aspx) and [RepeatDirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.repeatcolumns.aspx) properties.